# How to load string in textbox when form loads?

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I'm trying to load a string in my textbox when my form loads. Somehow nothing appears. Can somebody explain to me why this is so?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TestText = "hello";
        FolderLocation.Text = TestText;
    }
```

Comment: When you say "nothing appears" do you mean that you see the text box, but it is empty OR do you mean that the textbox itself is also not appearing?  In either case, based on this very small snippet it is very hard to say why that would be. Maybe the control is covered by another control.  Maybe the control is hidden. Please create a [mcve] which exhibits the problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. This is a very important clue that should make you look at your form and double check your control names, and also check that you aren't setting this anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I followed pstrjds 's prompt to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. Turns out I had an error in another part of the code that somehow led to the textbox unable to load any texts. Thanks a lot.